# All <p class="blah"> 'under' each H2

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, siblings

Firstly: I understand the `<p>s` are not really 'under' the `<h2>s` but are siblings here. I just needed to get the idea across in the Title.

My sample HTML looks like this:

```html
<h1>Wildlife near me</h1>

<h2>Animals</h2>
<p>Here are some animals.</p>
<p class="wildlife">Grey Kangaroo</p>
<p>A bit about kangaroos</p>
<p class="wildlife">Koala</p>
<p>These are NOT bears!</p>

<h2>Snakes</h2>
<p>These can be very dangerous! Always take care</p>
<p class="wildlife">Eastern Brown</p>
<p>A very aggressive and venomous snake</p>
<p>A link here to an ad, so we don't want this bit</p>
```

I've been trying to use BeautifulSoup to create a listing (yes, Markdown,but not relevant here) that is just the 'key' info, something like:

```markdown
# Animals
## Grey Kangaroo
A bit about kangaroos
## Koala
These are NOT bears!

# Snakes
## Eastern Brown
A very aggressive and venomous snake
```

How do I get all the `<p class="wildlife">Grey Kangaroo</p>` and it's next sibling..for each of the h2s?  I've tried this:

```py
for h2 in soup.find_all('h2'):
    print("#### ",h2.text)
    x = h2.find_next_siblings('p', class_='wildlife')
    for item in x:
        print("*",item.text,"*",sep="")
        print(item.find_next_sibling('p').text)
        print("    ")
    print("---")
```

But it goes too 'deep' on that first one (adding the 2nd one's data), then does the 2nd H2.

```markdown
####  Animals
*Grey Kangaroo*
A bit about kangaroos
    
*Koala*
These are NOT bears!
    
*Eastern Brown*
A very aggressive and venomous snake
    
---
####  Snakes
*Eastern Brown*
A very aggressive and venomous snake
    
---
```

Can this be done?  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like `dicts` to store structured information that could be reused in later proccessing.

So I select all `<p>` with `class` named `.wildlife` and iterate over to `find_previous('h2')` and `find_next('p')` and store information in `data`:

```
data = {}

for w in soup.select('h2~.wildlife'):
    
    if w.find_previous('h2').text not in data:
        data[w.find_previous('h2').text] = []
        
    data[w.find_previous('h2').text].append({
        'animal' : w.text,
        'note' : w.find_next('p').text
    })
```

Now you can process the data in the way you like:

```
for x in data:
    print('# '+ x)
    for a in data[x]:
        print('## ' + a['animal'])
        print(a['note'])
    print('------------------')
```

#### Example

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html='''
<h1>Wildlife near me</h1>

<h2>Animals</h2>
<p>Here are some animals.</p>
<p class="wildlife">Grey Kangaroo</p>
<p>A bit about kangaroos</p>
<p class="wildlife">Koala</p>
<p>These are NOT bears!</p>

<h2>Snakes</h2>
<p>These can be very dangerous! Always take care</p>
<p class="wildlife">Eastern Brown</p>
<p>A very aggressive and venomous snake</p>
<p>A link here to an ad, so we don't want this bit</p>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

data = {}

for w in soup.select('h2~.wildlife'):
    
    if w.find_previous('h2').text not in data:
        data[w.find_previous('h2').text] = []
        
    data[w.find_previous('h2').text].append({
        'animal' : w.text,
        'note' : w.find_next('p').text
    })
    

for x in data:
    print('# '+ x)
    for a in data[x]:
        print('## ' + a['animal'])
        print(a['note'])
    print('------------------')
```

#### Output

```
# Animals
## Grey Kangaroo
A bit about kangaroos
## Koala
These are NOT bears!
------------------
# Snakes
## Eastern Brown
A very aggressive and venomous snake
------------------
```

### EDIT

If you just like to print directly you can go with:

```
data = []

for w in soup.select('.wildlife'):
    
    h2 = w.find_previous('h2').text
    
    if h2 not in data:
        data.append(h2)
        print('------------------')
        print('# ' + h2)
        
    print ('## ' + w.text)
    print(w.find_next('p').text)
```

Comment: Aha, that's great. Thank you very much for not just giving an answer but explaining the 'why'.  I'm not a developer, but dabble. I know dictionaries and a bit on BeautifulSoup, but the idea of linking them - then using the 'not' etc logic  - is smart...and practical!